# Can I publish a directory using Ivy?

Tags: python, ivy

I have a python lib, and I want to use Ivy to manage my private libraries.

I python lib file structure looks like:

```
mylib\
    __init__.py
    f1.py
    f2.py
    ...
```

Now I want to publish `mylib` as a whole, instead file by file. In Ivy, I know how to publish one file by using the `artifact` tag. But how can I publish the whole directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a directory is that it's not very easy to version it's contents... The most common solution to this problem is to create a tar or zip package and publish this to your repository.

3rd party builds consuming the directory can either download and unpack it, or alternatively use the [packager](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html) resolver to access files inside the package.

The [packager](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html)  resolver does add some complexity, but it's a very powerful feature of ivy. The [ivy roundup](http://code.google.com/p/ivyroundup/) is an example of an ivy repository designed to hold packager files, making it easier to consume artifacts not available via normal repositories.

Finally, the following answers gives [packager](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html) resolver examples:

- [gradle - how to declare a dependency of a jar in a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445696/gradle-how-to-declare-a-dependency-of-a-jar-in-a-jar/3454359#3454359)
- [Issues using ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876160/issues-using-ivy/2878131#2878131)
- [ivy dependency on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987108/ivy-dependency-on-external-jar/7464028#7464028)
- [Ivy Custom Resolvers for Git or TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294996/ivy-custom-resolvers-for-git-or-tfs/9351126#9351126)
- [Apache Ivy: resolving dependencies embedded in an installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908371/apache-ivy-resolving-dependencies-embedded-in-an-installer/2149883#2149883)