# Can I use distributionmanagement in maven to distribute a directory of files?

Tags: maven

I've got a maven project which generates a set of resources files using some plugins defined in a pom.xml. I'd like to use something like distributionManagement to push these generated files to a branch in Git. I can see that I can use something like Apache Wagon to do the distribution but the distributionManagement settings seem to only cater for the repository, site and relocation elements.

Is there a way of adding some custom distributionManagement elements, or can anyone suggest another way of pushing my generated resources to a git branch?

Comment: it's generally a bad practice to put generated stuff in Source Code Management system

Comment: Similar question to this one: (ivy and maven are both dependency management technologies) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009339/can-i-publish-a-directory-using-ivy/

Answer (score 0):

Use a usual maven project, put the generated of the resources into the **generate-resources** life-cycle phase and package the result into a jar file and finally use the usual deployment (** mvn deploy **) or in relationship with creating a release to transfer the resulting artifacts into a maven repository.